# Automatically update plugin versions in mutlimodule projct

Tags: maven, plugins, version

Is there a way to automatically update the versions of plugins for every module in a multimodule maven project?

Maven versions plugin can be used only to update project dependencies version, but not plugin versions.

Comment: The question is: It sounds as you have defined versions in modules of a multi module? If so please refactor and only define versions of plugins in pluginManagement in the root of your multi module build ...or maybe in a corporate pom ...

Comment: I'm not aware of something that updates all the plugins, but the versions plugin has at least a report goal to do this: https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-plugin-updates.html